# Node JS and MS Build - Is This Possible?

Tags: .net, node.js, msbuild, compression, uglifyjs

I am writing MS Build task for JavaScript compression and I hoped I could use Uglify as my compression provider.

Since Uglify is written in JavaScript I obviously needed a .NET port. Fortunately, there seem to be at least two possible options - [Uglify CS](http://uglifycs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/808ccbe561db) and [Uglify.NET](https://github.com/asbjornu/Uglify.NET/tree/master/lib). Unfortunately both haven't seen a single commit in the last year therefore I suppose they don't support the new version 2 of Uglify :)

Having this in mind I was wondering is there a way to somehow eval the original code from a .NET build task? Or more generally said, is there a way to invoke Node.JS from .NET?

I can imagine calling Node.JS service from my task, however, this seems to be an overkill.

Comment: You can use Uglify from the DOS command line right? If so, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to call it from a MS Build Task.

Comment: Well, yes, you are technically right, one can call uglify from the cmd as long as there is node installed on the machine. I will give that one a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in a build task (pre-build is probably what you want.) Simply add a call to node "my-script-to-uglify.js", and every time you build... presto!

Also, in my case I actually included a node binary in the project (all devs were on same architecture, not all had node)

Comment: Thx for sharing that. That was only concern, what to do in the case of not all the people have Node installed.